# How would I call a function by using a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently found some code that calls a function from a different directory like this:

```
modules["module_name"].function(parameters)
```

Then I had a thought about calling a function (but not a module; I already know how to do that) through lists in that format like so:

```
[function_name](parameters)
```

Comment: You can do that, but you wouldn't really want to do that. Just import the other module with the usual `import function_name from module_name` syntax

Comment: "then I had a thought about calling a function ... through lists in that format like so" What exactly do you mean by this? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: You can only access elements of a list by specifying an integer index, so `[function_name]` would never work (assuming `function_name` is a string) — so you'll need to think different.

Comment: @martineau one of the answers (form @smerkd) used a dictionary (not a list like youre thinking) to call the function just like the way I called the module from a different directory.

Comment: I said that because the title of your question is "How would I call a function by using a list?" and you said "…through lists in that format" in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function like that in a list. I don't know what that syntax you have there. t's not possible, but you can call method references from dicts or variables below

If you're function is stored in a dictionary like so

```py
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

some_dict = {
   'add' : add
}
```

Then you can call it like so

```py
some_dict['add'](10, 10)
```

Comment: so I tried it out by running the program itself, and it worked. then I tried the importing from other directory and it called the function twice...

Comment: Did you put some_dict['add'](10, 10) in both files? As in did you call the function in the other file and called it in the one you imported it? Remember python will run the code in the import file when you import. So if you call a function in that file it will run when imported. Think of an import as running the file as a function (abstract way of viewing it)

Comment: ill have to check

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function using list... you can have a list of functions and call it out from index

```py
def foo(arg):
  print(arg)

list_of_functions = [foo]
list_of_functions[0](3)
```

This also works with dictionaries, since functions are just pointers, as anything else.

But i believe you wanted to find the function by the name from variable, in that case, probably (idk, never went this route) use `globals` for that one

```py
def foo(arg):
    print(arg)
    
function_name = 'foo'
globals()[function_name](3)
```

P.S. I still wonder about 2.7 though

Comment: well the syntax is basically a way it might work, which I know it won't. but ill try what you put because it look relatively similar to what I was thinking (I just noticed the period in the second code block XD)

Answer (score 0):

If the list is created in other module :

module.py it should looks like this:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

lista = [add]
```

And you could call the fuction like this in your own module:

```
from module import lista

res = lista[0](2,3)
print(res)
```

The important here is note that the function should be define before to list it and in the same module where the list is created. In other way your code will be broken.

Don't ask why but I have python 2.7 too